# Random number issue with Next method (.NET Framework)

Tags: c#, .net, random

I need to generate a lot of random numbers which must be anywhere between 1 and int.MaxValue. The arguments passed to the Next method of the Random class are not always the same. In one senario the arguments might be as follows:

```
Next(1, int.MaxValue);
```

In another they might as well be:

```
Next(1, 2);
```

The issue here is that whenever you pass values like 1 and 2 or 99 and 100, the lower number is always the "random" number returned by the method. The reason for this is because the method subtracts 1 from the maximum value (unless min and max are the same) and then gives you the random number. How would I go about generating a range of random numbers within a range of numbers, as stated above, without getting this predictable outcome?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to pass the inclusive upper bound + 1, ie:

```
var result = rand.Next(1, 2+1); // Returns 1 or 2
var result2 = rand.Next(99, 101); // Returns 99 or 100
```

Note that this won't work for `int.MaxValue`, of course.  There is no way to have `Random` directly return `int.MaxValue`.  To get a [0,int.MaxValue] result, you would need to do:

```
var result = rand.Next(-1, int.MaxValue) + 1;
```

Comment: I don't think .NET would like int.MaxValue + 1.

Answer (score 4):

The upper bound is exclusive, not inclusive.  Given that, the range [1,2) only contains one number, 1, not two.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx), the first parameter to `Next(int, int)` is "The **inclusive** lower bound", while the second is "The **exclusive** upper bound".

If you want to generate a random number that might be `1` or `2`, you should use the following call:

```
rand.Next(1, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a method that takes the lower and upper limits and gives you what you're looking for?

Example:

```
    public int GetRandom(int lower, int upper)
    {
        return upper == int.MaxValue ? rand.Next(lower - 1, upper) + 1 : rand.Next(lower, upper + 1);
    }
```

If the upper limit is int.MaxValue, it shifts the range down by 1 and then adds it back after it gives the random number. Otherwise, it adds 1 to the upper limit and then gives you the random number.

Then when you use it, you'll just do something like:

```
    var randomOne = GetRandom(1, 2);
    var randomTwo = GetRandom(99,int.MaxValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
  class Program
  {
    static readonly Random r = new Random();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetRandom(i));
        }
    }

    private static int GetRandom(int i)
    {
        return 1 + (r.Next(int.MaxValue)%i);
    }
  }
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can get `int.MaxValue` by adding `1` after getting random `int`:

```
var result = rand.Next(1, int.MaxValue) + 1;
```

Comment: Doing it this way, you'll never get the lower bound.

Comment: Lower bound can be set 1 less than the actual lower bound.

Comment: All you've done is shift from adding 1 to the upper to subtracting 1 from the lower......